# How to create a bash function that return to the current prompt?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to create a bash function that return to the current line?

For example

```
#~/.bashrc
do-magic() {
    # do some magic and return the input to current prompt line
    # for example "hello"
}
bind -x '"\C-e":do-magic'
```

Then

```
$ echo <ctrl+e>
# become
$ echo hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of Bash 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994563/integrate-readlines-kill-ring-and-the-x11-clipboard/1088763) you can do this by changing the `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` variables inside the function. (The 'point' is the current cursor position.) For example:

```sh
_paste() {
    local str="Hello $(date +%F)!"
    local len=${#str}
    # Note: Bash 5.x wants the length in characters, but Bash 4.x apparently
    #       wanted bytes. To properly insert non-ASCII text, you used to need:
    # local len=$(printf '%s' "$str" | wc -c)

    # Insert the text in between [0..cursor] and [cursor..end]
    READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${str}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}
    # Advance the cursor
    READLINE_POINT=$((READLINE_POINT + len))
}

bind -x '"\C-e": _paste'
```

Comment: With a static string this is over-complicated; compare `bind '"\C-e":"Hello!"'`. Yet for a non-static string (e.g. `local str="$(date)"`) this is the way to go. +1

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: True, but OP did ask for "magic". I copied my example from a "paste from X11 clipboard and apply shell quoting" function, so it started as `str=$(pclip); str=${str@Q}`.

Comment: I commented with other users in mind. If I was a rather clueless user and I wanted to insert a static string, and I came across this answer, then I would be glad to know there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "expect"

here you have a detailed example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953253/5521600

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).