# Ctrl X-E without executing command immediately

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

It's very handy that you can type complex commands in the $EDITOR (`vim` in my case) with <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>E</kbd></kbd> in Bash.

However, in my opinion it would be even better if the command were not executed immediately but rather just pasted to the command line so that I can make final adjustments based on previous commands/output. Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: Which editor are you actually using? (`$EDITOR` can be any editor the user chooses, as it's a variable.)

Comment: I know. I use vim

Comment: We didn't know though, because you didn't tell us

Comment: the fix I was looking for should work with any editor (like the one in the accepted answer)

Comment: Ctrl X/E is an editor-specific sequence, hence the request for clarification

Comment: @roaima Actually, Ctrl+X-E is completely editor agnostic in this case.  It's a default keybinding in Bash that is being discussed here, not an editor keybinding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot tell if you will call it simple. This is a quick and dirty proof of concept:

```bash
# in Bash

_edit_wo_executing() {
    local editor="${EDITOR:-nano}"
    tmpf="$(mktemp)"
    printf '%s\n' "$READLINE_LINE" > "$tmpf"
    "$editor" "$tmpf"
    READLINE_LINE="$(<"$tmpf")"
    READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}"
    rm -f "$tmpf"  # -f for those who have alias rm='rm -i'
}

bind -x '"\C-x\C-e":_edit_wo_executing'
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd></kbd> should do what you want.

Notes:

- I used only basic logic to set `editor`; adjust it to your needs.
- `READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}"` should place the cursor at the very end. Bash 5 wants the length in characters and the above code works; but Bash 4 wants bytes. To handle non-ASCII text in Bash 4 use

  ```
  READLINE_POINT="$(printf '%s' "$READLINE_LINE" | wc -c)"
  ```

  (I learned from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1463001/432690)).
- Upon the keystroke, the function executes in your current shell, so (unlike in a script) your aliases will work. The `-f` in `rm -f` was suggested by a fellow user who uses `alias rm='rm -i'`. In general you may want to [run unaliased `rm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39291/108618).

Comment: Thanks. I put it .bashrc and it works fine indeed.

Comment: my EDITOR was set to `emacs -nw` and I got error: `"bash: emacs -nw: command not found"`. To fix this error, I had to remove quotes i.e. change `"$editor" "$tmpf"` to `$editor "$tmpf"`

Comment: For me it didn't like the _ in the name. I changed it to `edit_wo_executing` and it worked.

Comment: It seems to work, but I'm getting a strange error. Only the first word of the edited command is executed, everything else is ignored

Comment: @Levi This code used to work in 2020, but now in 2023 (in Bash 5.2.15) I'm getting errors indeed. Strangely, for me it's *opposite* of what you described, i.e. the first word is ignored and the rest taken as a command. Investigating.

Comment: The behavior is the same even if I remove the whole command and type something different, it will only execute the first word.

Comment: Switching to zsh solved it for me :)

Comment: I fixed it [here](https://gist.github.com/sebastiancarlos/69a198bebd45bb4ea58d0d4646f33966). Basically, I fixed it by adding `local` before `tmpf="$(mktemp)"`, and doing `>|` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

While this does not directly answer your question, in the `zsh` and `fish` shells (and likely others), the behavior you requested is the default.

Closing the editor will paste the command in your current shell without executing it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind - I added the Fish shell to your answer rather than creating a new answer.  I agree that this is useful information, even though it doesn't directly answer the question, but I also don't think we need a separate answer for every shell ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds sure, any useful info is welcome!