# Change strings in commands to another strings in a smarter way

Tags: bash, script, computer-behavior

I know that:

```
$ command -[options] string string2
```

Can be easily changed with:

```
$ ^string^string3
```

To obtain:

```
$ command -[options] string3 string2
```

What else can I do with it, like I'm trying to make it twice, in a row:

```
$ ^string3^string && ^string2^string4
```

or after a command

```
$ ffmpeg -i file output.mp4 && ^.mp4^.mp3
```

or

```
$ echo blue && ^blue^red
^blue^red: command not found
```

***doesn't work***

or

```
$ echo blue
blue
$ ^blue^red && ^red^purple
red blueblue red^purple
```

***not working***

or

```
$ echo blue
$ ^blue^red^red^purple
echo redred^purple
redred^purple
```

***still not working***

---

It's for a bash scripting, and the most short thing that I know is ^...^...

I need a short and easy command to accomplish that,

With this examples you get the idea,

What is necessary? Someone sugested me:

```
$ echo blue && !#:s/blue/purple/ true
echo blue && echo purple &&  true
blue
purple
```

The result was very much kind what I expected but ended up with `>` and the command couldn't be completed. UPDATE: I fixed by adding true at the end of it.

---

This question was previously in StackOverflown and was recommended it to be here!

Comment: I would say "Bash scripting" means "designing scripts meant to be interpreted by Bash". The techniques you mentioned [can be used in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314933/108618) but usually they are not. Your examples strongly suggest interactive usage (there is `$` as the prompt); my answer follows this clue. When really writing a script, you're already in some editor which probably supports copying and pasting. Then the bold fragment of my answer applies.

Comment: Where can I know everything about Linux OS, I'm tired to not understand some important and old school concepts, I would like to read everything at once instead of random parts over internet, if you can point me an official page that would be great, because I don't know if it's POSIX or GNU or Bash manual.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Besides I've being using Emacs and Vim, a long time in the past, for me it's little better Vim, usually I use nano. I'm not sure your method, indeed is helpful, my question was about changing specifics parts which I believe it's called "bash history expansion", I'm not sure, I discovered right now while doing a search.

Comment: There is no single place to read about Linux OS. There is no such thing as single Linux OS. Linux is a kernel. Different distributions ship Linux kernel with everything else needed to constitute a functional OS. This usually (but not necessarily) includes Bash. `man 1 bash` is close to "everything at once" *about Bash*. [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is probably closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: All of these shortcuts are for interactive use, not for scripting. They're all part of bash's history system, which is normally disabled in scripts (and probably should be left disabled).

Second: The `^original^replacement` syntax is what's called a "quick replacement", and it's meant to be (as the name implies) a quick way to rerun the last command with a simple change. It 's *not* extensible beyond that basic purpose -- there's no way to make multiple changes with this syntax. But you can with the more general (but verbose) syntax: `!!` designates the last command (actually, line; see below), and you can add modifiers like `:s/original/replacement/` to make changes. Here's an example with two substitutions:

```
$ echo string1 string2
string1 string2
$ !!:s/1/3/:s/2/4/
echo string3 string4
string3 string4
```

Third: as I said, this history recall & replay feature really works on lines (or multiline commands), not simple commands. Here's an example of that:

```
$ echo "command one"; echo "command two"
command one
command two
$ echo "command three" && !!:s/command/line/
echo "command three" && echo "line one"; echo "command two"
command three
line one
command two
```

Note that `!!:s/command/line/` didn't recall the previous command, `echo "command three"`, or even `echo "command two"`, but the entire previous line! Also, even though `command` occurred twice in that line, the substitution was only performed once. If you want all occurrences replaced ("global replacement"), add the `g` modifier (`!!:gs/original/replacement/`). There are a [number of other modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html) you can use.

Finally: this can get complicated and it's easy to mis-predict what's going to happen when you press return. Kamil Maciorowski's suggestion of interactively recalling and editing the previous command lets you see the command before you press return, so I'd recommend that method instead.

Actually, what I usually do myself is hit up-arrow to get the previous command back, then use bash's built-in line editing capability to make the changes I want.

Comment: Thanks you answer lead me more closer to what I want, I believe it's called "bash history expansion", I'll read all GNU to get better at Bash, I'm not sure if I should move to zsh instead, since some say it's going to be the new standard of shell

Comment: Indeed somebody have recommended me the use of `true` at the end, like `!!:s/string1/string2/ true` -- serves as `<RETURN>` I think

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>↑</kbd> and make the command you want to alter appear in the command line. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to edit it in your preferred editor.

**It depends on the editor and your familiarity with it how shortly and easily you can make the changes you want.** To execute, save the file under whatever name the editor offers and exit the editor.

Pick your editor by setting `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` variable. From `man 1 bash`:

> `edit-and-execute-command` (`C-xC-e`)
> Invoke  an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands. Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

Note key bindings can be configured. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is the default for what I'm talking about.

Additionally you may find this useful: [*ctrl-x-e without executing command immediately*](https://superuser.com/q/1601543/432690)