# Can I add a newline into a command from bash's history?

Tags: bash, cygwin, tmux

I often stumble across this problem:

1. I type a command that has multiple lines for readability. This is an example:

   ```
    echo "Hello. This is an example
    of a very long command which is
    divided into lines. This is pretty cool and easy to understand."
   ```
2. When I press Enter, I realize that a line is missing in the command. In this example, it could be that I want another linebreak before "pretty".
3. When I press <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Left</kbd>, I can edit the command and delete or insert new characters, but how can I insert a new linebreak? When I move the caret before "pretty", <kbd>Enter</kbd> (as well as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) just executes the command.

(I am inside tmux inside cygwin, just in case that makes a difference)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512327/how-to-insert-newline-in-a-already-existing-bash-string-on-the-command-line

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1636232/432690).

Comment: I like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19512558/6403504 with *Ctrl + k*, *Ctrl + y* best, but these all are just workarounds. So, I guess, that feature just does not exist in Bash.

Comment: In Linux press Ctrl+v, Ctrl+j. I haven't tested in Cygwin.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that works great, even when reusing the Ctrl for the j.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but works...

```
b@localhost:/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.34-bib/net> echo -e "a
b
d
e"
a
b
d
e
b@localhost:/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.34-bib/net> echo -e "a
b\nc
d
e"
a
b
c
d
e
```

You could always copy & paste.